# Create multiple ZIP files from a single folder without zipping the whole folder

Tags: command-line, zip

I have a problematic web server install where someone has dumped all photo files into a single directory - there are over 250k files - 23 gigs in total on a server with limited space.

I'm looking for a terminal command that would help me extract these files from the server.

What I'm trying to do is create a smaller number of manageable zip files from this single directory, leaving the original directory intact.

For example, create 10 ZIP files each containing 25000 images
myfiles1.zip
myfiles2.zip
myfiles3.zip and so on

Is this even possible?

I know I can ZIP the whole directory, but I dont have the disk space to zip 23gb and then run a split, creating another 23gb of files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've not provided any OS or release details. Why ask here?

Comment: Can we assume sane (no newlines, no spaces, no globbing characters or apostrophes) file names or do our solutions need to work for arbitrary names?

Comment: Firstly, I'm asking here because this is all new to me - I'm using the Terminal window on CPANEL on a webserver

Comment: All file names are something.jpg - mostly camera files eg IMG_12345.jpg

Comment: *I'm using the Terminal window on CPANEL on a webserver*... Yes, but is it Ubuntu? For Linux questions about anything there's Unix&Linux. AU is exclusively for Ubuntu and official derivatives.

Comment: Read `man find xargs head tail seq`. Use these tools and it's easy.